# SQL value won't change as image changes in dynamic Lightbox gallery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, image, lightbox

I have tried many hours just to get this tiny piece of information to show, I need help before I decide to brake my laptop in two pieces.

I am trying to get an uploaded image to display a caption along with username (person who uploaded it) and date. These three values are stored in my database, the upload works fine. As I loop through the directory to display my images, I cannot get these values (passed as variables) to display correctly, rather the last upload input is the only one that displays for every image in my gallery.

I assume there is something wrong in my loop code and will post it here in hope that it is a simple overlooked fact.

> ```
> //Open directory
> $dir_handle = opendir($thumb_dir) or die('Error opening thumbnail directory.');
> while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) { //go through files
>     //if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
>     $file_parts = explode('.', $file); //split filename and put extensions in array
>     $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts)); //last element file extension
>
>     //Filename w/o extension.
>     $title = implode('.', $file_parts); //only filename
>     $title = htmlspecialchars($title); //security measure
>
>     $dbconnect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'peter', '1234', 'dt091g');
>     $query = 'SELECT username, date FROM image_info';
>     $result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
>     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
>     $username = $row['username'];
>     $date = $row['date'];
>     }
>
>     //add every image if good extension
>     if (in_array($ext, $allowed_exts)) {
>         echo '<a class="example-image-link" 
>               href="'.$img_dir.$file.'" 
>               data-lightbox="example-set" 
>               data-title="'.$username.$date.'">
>               <img class="example-image" src="'.$thumb_dir.$file.'" alt="hello"/>
>               </a>';
>
>     $i++; //increment the image counter
>     }
> }
>
> closedir($dir_handle); ?>
> ```

I am assuming I must incorporate the unique ID somehow, and I have tried myself blind, but still end up with only the last value for any row of my db table.

Appreciate any kind of input, even if you're just writing to say 'Duh! You idiot'.

EDIT: Showing a record of image_info

> ```
> $image_info = array(   array('id' => '50','username' => 'Peter','date'
> => '05052015','filename' => '20140808_220541.jpg','mimetype' => 'image/jpeg','filesize' => '2404856','caption' => 'Norwegian
> Mountains'));
> ```

Comment: Don't you need to pass the image name into the SQL query to know which user is associated with it? `SELECT username, date FROM image_info where image_name = ?`

Comment: If you're not going to output  $username and $date in the loop, then you have to build them as arrays, for echoing out later $username[] = $row['username'];    $date[] = $row['date']; You may have to initiate them first. Then, when you come to echo them out in the next bit of code, you could use $username[$i]. - But I'm no php coder

Comment: I tried stating `SELECT username, date FROM image_info WHERE id = ?` and that just gives me `Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in...`.

Comment: could you post sample of few records from `image_info` ?

Comment: Strawberry's answer seemed to do the trick, now it all just seems logical that I had to make them arrays. 'Duh, you idiot.'. This may of course not be an optimal solution, just part of my learning process. Thanks guys!

Comment: You could pull all the users for each file but you don't need to. This will build that array numerous times whereas you only actually need 1 value per query (the username and date).

Comment: I commented to quickly, Strawberry's tip seemed to work since it displayed the different usernames and dates, however, they are not attached to correct image. So I assume I need that unique ID connection as suggested by chris85?

Comment: Here is one of the records from `image_info`... `$image_info = array(
  array('id' => '50','username' => 'Peter','date' => '05052015','filename' => '20140808_220541.jpg','mimetype' => 'image/jpeg','filesize' => '2404856','caption' => 'Norwegian Mountains')
);`